# Generics code fails to compile without intermediate variable

Tags: java, generics

I am surprised that the first 2 lines of code in `main` below are allowed by the compiler. It seems to be trusting me when I say that `getIt()` will return a `Dog` even though the signature also allows a `Cat` to be returned.

```
public class GenericsAreWeird {
    public static void main(String... args){
        // This is fine
        Dog d = getIt();
        d.woof();

        // This fails to compile
        // getIt().woof();

        // This compiles but gives a runtime ClassCastException
        Cat c = getIt();
        c.meow();
    }

    private static <T extends Animal> T getIt(){
        return (T) new Dog();
    }

    public static class Animal {}

    public static class Cat extends Animal{
        public void meow(){}
    }

    public static class Dog extends Animal{
        public void woof(){}
    }
}
```

I generally trust Java generics to protect me from ClassCastExceptions by giving compiler errors, rather than telling me at runtime that something won't work, so allowing this seems broken.

It also seems counter-intuitive that:

```
Dog d = getIt();
d.woof();
```

is not exactly equivalent to:

```
getIt().woof();
```

the compiler needs the intermediate variable as a 'hint'.

Have generics always worked this way? Can someone point me to (or provide) a decent explanation of any other scenarios where the compiler fails to pick up a class-related error like this?

Comment: Just btw, that line (`getIt().woof()`) can compile with a little help (`GenericsAreWeird.<Dog>getIt().woof()`) - but this adds nothing to the type safety.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return (T) new Dog();` for the most part tells the compiler to
"shut up with your type checking, I know better than you that `Dog` will always be assignable to `T`"
to which the compiler replies
"okay, go ahead then, then you better take care of not ever calling this method expecting it to return a anything else / a`Cat`"

Then you *do* call it expecting it to return a `Cat` and get a deserved `ClassCastException`. You get a runtime exception because you tell the compiler that you know it better (which you do not).

Answer (score 2):

After type erasure your `getIt()` method will look very much like this:

```
  private static Animal getIt(){
    return new Dog();
  }
```

But before the type erasure happens, the compiler sees, that you use a generic return type `T extends Animal` for the method! And thus, once it sees the line

```
Dog d = getIt();
```

it says: Ok, so `T` will be `Dog` in this particular case, so I need to insert a cast to `Dog` after type erasure like this:

```
Dog d = (Dog) getIt();
```

In the same way, for the call `Cat c = getIt()` it will resolve the type `T` to be `Cat` and add an according cast to Cat:

```
Cat c = (Cat) getIt();
```

But inside of your method the compiler warns you: Hey, are you sure, that the `Dog` you create will always be of type `T`? Remember, this is not guaranteed generally! So if you ignore this warning, you should know, what you are doing, taht's the point.

And finally, of course the call

```
getIt().woof()
```

will not compile, because in this case the compiler has no idea how to resolve the type `T`, so it will be just `Animal`, the upper limitation of `T`. It is not able to guess that it is a `Dog` only based on the call to the `woof()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The following line:

```
 getIt().woof();
```

fails because `woof()` is defined on `Dog` not `Animal` and `getIt()` returns a sub-class of `Animal`. Hence the compiler is unaware of `woof()`.

You could try:

```
 abstract class Animal { abstract void speak(); }
 class Dog extends Animal { void speak() { // Dog specific implementation } }
 class Cat extends Animal { void speak() { // Cat specific implementation } }
```

Then you could use:

```
 getIt().speak();
```

You get a `ClassCastException` because the only information about the type returned by `getIt()` is that it is a sub-class of `Animal`. Assigning it to a variable of type `Cat` or `Dog` is unsafe. This would be true of any similar use of generics.

A common workaround is to define `getIt()` something like this:

```
<T extends Animal> T getIt(Class<T> clazz) {
    // return an instance of the appropriate type based on clazz
}
```

You can use it thus:

```
Dog dog = getIt(Dog.class);
```

Comment: thanks, I understand why that line fails to compile, it just seems strange that the 2-line equivalent is allowed - I didn't expect using an intermediate variable to make any difference

Comment: It's true it's allowed, but it is un-safe and there was probably a compiler warning about that at some point. After all, you are assigning a `Dog` to a variable of type `Cat`.